# '<> is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased' even though keyReleased is not used

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I am receiving two errors whilst creating this class. The first appears at:

```
public class DisplayerDeluxe extends JPanel implements ActionListener, 
KeyListener{
```

The following compiler error is being shown: `DisplayerDeluxe is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener`

The next error is shown here

```
public void startGame() {
        paintCurrent(0, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                bRef[i][j].addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { //Error is shown here
                        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                            mazeBuilder.buildPath();
                            Grid grid = mazeBuilder.getGrid();
                            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && getYPos() != 0
                            && !getCell(getXPos(), getYPos(), grid).hasNorth()) {
                                moveUp();
                            }
                            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && getYPos() != height - 1
                            && !getCell(getXPos(), getYPos(), grid).hasSouth()) {
                                moveDown();
                            }
                            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && getXPos() != 0
                            && !getCell(getXPos(), getYPos(), grid).hasWest()) {
                                moveLeft();
                            }
                            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && getXPos() != width - 1
                            && !getCell(getXPos(), getYPos(), grid).hasEast()) {
                                moveRight();
                            }
                            else {
                                infoBox("Only arrow key input in a dirrection " +
                                    "not blocked by a wall is valid.", "Maze Game");
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        infoBox("Welcome to the maze game! Navigate your way to the end by using the arrow keys!", "Maze Game");
    }
```

The error reads: `<anonymous DisplayerDeluxe$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener`

This is confusing me greatly because nowhere in my code do I include keyReleased() and keyPressed() has the @Override notation. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your ned to override all three method in the class whether you use them are not. keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) . It is because you are using the KeyListener interface.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realise that all of the methods had to be overridden! This has been giving me a headache for the last hour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `new KeyListener() { ... }` you're creating what's known as an anonymous inner class that extends `KeyListener` and creates an unnamed instance of it (hence anonymous). The error is complaining that your anonymous inner class, displayed as `<anonymous DisplayerDeluxe$1>`, is neither abstract nor does it implement the method `keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)` as described in `java.awt.event.KeyListener`.

[KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) is an interface that contracts implementors to provide 3 methods. This means all classes, anonymous inner classes included, that implement this interface must either be abstract (and therefore not obliged to provide an implementation) or concrete/normal class with implementations provided. Anonymous inner classes are always concrete, never abstract, and therefore must always implement all methods required.

The solution to this, without using other classes, is to implement the other two methods. As you have no desired functionality for them, you can probably leave them empty and do nothing. Most IDEs should actually help you with this as, when you start creating the anonymous inner class, they will prompt to generate the unimplemented methods for you.

Alternately, you can extend another class that may have some or all of those methods already implemented with stubs such as `KeyAdapter`, but ultimately all methods must be implemented one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Use a KeyAdapter instead.  It has built-in stubs.

```
bRef[i][j].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()...
```